# How to correctly pass an argument to a pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, arguments, pthreads, void

I am trying to figure out a way to get my program to produce two beeps at the same time using the Beep() function in the windows.h library.  I have decided to do this using a couple of pthreads.  However, I am having trouble creating a passable set of arguments.

I am pretty new to programming and don't know much about type_casting or void* syntax/rules/purpose.  I know it's a pointer to data of any type.  I would love to understand as much as I can about multithreading and void*s as they seem very useful.  If anyone can suggest some good articles or tutorials (made with the beginner in mind) I would really appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;



 void *tone(void *note)
 {
     double freq;
     freq = double(note);
     Beep(freq, 5000);
 }

 int main()
 {
     double C5 = 523.25;
     double D5 = 587.33;
     double E5 = 659.25;
     double F5 = 698.46;
     double G5 = 783.99;
     double A5 = 880.00;
     double B5 = 987.77;
     double C6 = 1046.50;

     pthread_t tone1;
     pthread_t tone2;

     pthread_create(&tone1, NULL, tone, (void *) C5);

 }
```

Also, I hope my code posts correctly.  I've only done this once before.

Comment: It would help a lot if you tag this with what language you are using. But generally, a simple pattern is to create a `struct` that holds all the parameters you need to pass to the thread. Allocate an instance of that struct, fill it out, pass a pointer to it to the thread, and allow the thread to deallocate it when it's done with it.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should be aware that the pthread library (aka POSIX threads) is a threading library for POSIX systems, which is most modern OSes these days *except* for Windows; but `<windows.h>` is very much a Windows-only header, so you should never be mixing the two in the same program, unless you're developing against an emulation or compatibility layer or similar (such as with Cygwin on Windows, or with Wine on Linux).

Whichever threading library you use, though, the answer is still the same.  Both of POSIX's `pthread_create()` and Windows' `CreateThread()`/`_beginthreadex()` take a `void*` parameter that gets passed through to your thread procedure.  But you don't have to actually pass a real pointer value if you don't want to—the OS treats it as an opaque blob and passes it through unmodified.  So as long as the data you want to pass is no larger than a pointer, you can just cast it to a pointer on the way in and cast it back on the other side.

For example, if you want to pass an integer to a thread procedure:

```
int theAnswer = 42;
pthread_create(..., &thread_proc, (void *)(intptr_t)theAnswer);
...
void *thread_proc(void *param) {
    int theAnswer = (int)(intptr_t)param;  // Contains 42
    ...
}
```

Your example passes a `double` value, which on 64-bit systems is likely to be the same size as a pointer, so you could pull off the same trick e.g. with a `union`; but it will certainly be larger than a pointer on 32-bit systems.

In order to pass more than a pointer's worth of data to a thread procedure, you need to put that data somewhere in memory and then pass, well, a pointer to that data.  The tricky part is managing that memory, especially in the case of creating multiple threads using the same thread procedure.

A common mistake is to allocate that data on the stack and create several threads in a loop whose argument points to that stack data.  However, all of those threads will point to the *same* stack data, and the actual data they end up reading becomes a big race condition with lots of Undefined Behavior.

The *correct* way to manage the memory is to allocate it dynamically for each thread, and then have the new thread be responsible for freeing the memory.  Each thread gets its own copy of the data, no memory is leaked, and there are no race conditions there.

Here's an example that will work regardless of whether or not a `double` is larger than a pointer (i.e., both 32-bit and 64-bit systems):

```
// Allocate dynamic memory for the thread parameter.  If you want to pass more
// than one value, create a struct instead.
double *theAnswer = new double(42.0);
pthread_create(..., &thread_proc, theAnswer);
...
void *thread_proc(void *param) {
    // Order of operations here is important: dereference the value first, then
    // free the memory
    double *theAnswerPtr = (double *)param;
    double theAnswer = *theAnswerPtr;
    delete theAnswerPtr;
    // theAnswer is now 42.0, use it
    ...
}
```